# Attribute pubdate not allowed on element time at this point

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have an HTML 5 document containing the element:

```
<time datetime='2013-04-18T12:57:59+01:00' pubdate='pubdate'>Thu, 18 Apr 2013 at 0:57PM</time>
```

This doesn't validate. The error is

> Attribute pubdate not allowed on element time at this point.

Any idea how to correct this validation error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made a little research on this subject and it seems that the best way to get around this is to use `itemprop="datePublished"` attribute.

Check out the [code example published at w3.org](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/#the-time-element):

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <h1 itemprop="headline">Small tasks</h1>
  <footer>Published <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2009-08-30">yesterday</time>.</footer>
  <p itemprop="articleBody">I put a bike bell on his bike.</p>
</article>
```

Changed my code like that and now validation is passed.

`itemprop="published"` is also possible when using a `fictional microdata vocabulary`. Here is the code that validates successfully too:

```
Posted on <time itemprop="published" datetime="2014-06-24T17:00:00+00:00">June 24, 2014</time>
```

**Note:** As xmojmr has commented, `itemprop` must go with appropriate `itemscope itemtype="..."` to validate properly.

**Reference**

- [schema.org/Article](http://schema.org/Article)
- [schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemscope_itemtype](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemscope_itemtype)
- "Google suggests using microdata" in [About rich snippets and structured data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/99170?hl=en)

Comment: More relevant reference then a "code example" is the ```schema.org``` specification at http://schema.org/Article. This is the place where the ```itemprop``` comes from. Backed by Google, Bing, Yahoo and others..

Comment: the ```itemprop``` markup does not w3c validate without proper http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemscope_itemtype

Comment: [Another useful discussion](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pupdate-validation-issue "WordPress › Support » pubdate validation issue") on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Could be the pubdate attribute is being removed from the specifications.
So just don't use pubdate.

Comment: a Bruce Lawson's article from 2012 claims that the ```pubdate``` attribute was dropped from the html specification as not needed, see http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/best-of-time. Correct replacement for use by search engines seems to be using the microformats, see http://schema.org/docs/faq.html#1